# Does my rails server have a memory leak?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, memory-leaks, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I have a couple EC2 servers running rails. When I first deploy (or redeploy) my code and restart the server, CPU usage is always 0.09% give or take 0.01%. Then over the course of a day it goes up and down with traffic, but ultimately always ends up around 0.5%. The next day it's around 1%, then 1.5%, and so on in that pattern.

I checked NewRelic, and I don't see anything in particular out of order, but I'm not entirely sure what to look for. I can log into the server itself and check things, but I'm not really that experienced with dev-ops kind of stuff.

Is something wrong with my server or my code? Where should I check first and how? Could this be a memory leak?

Comment: You would see memory usage increase if you had a memory leak, not CPU usage.  One thing to check is the database.  You may have unoptimized queries running against tables which are steadily growing after each redeploy.  You can check also check your logs to see how long some of the more frequent queries are taking.

Comment: A memory leak might be consistent with higher CPU if it meant that the GC had to run more frequently (newrelic will show you how often GC is running). I find rack-mini-profiler useful for leaks.